# How to delete row, when timestamp is exactly like another timestamp

Tags: database, oracle

I have 1 table that have a timestamp column, I'm trying to delete a row that the timestamp column is a primary key, so how can I delete the row?

For example:

```
Delete from access where timeStamp_column = '13/04/18 07:15:31,123457000';
```

Something like this, I've been searching but all I have found is "How to delete a timestamp older than etc", I need it to be identical to what I write

Thanks, people!

Excuse me for my English :)

Comment: if it's a primary key, then you can't actually have 2 rows with the same value

Comment: You title suggests you have two timestamps at the same value, but that is impossible if it is a primary key, like @thatjeffsmith pointed out.  But the query in your question is actually correct.  The only thing you need to do is make sure the string you send is in the proper format for Oracle timestamp data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're relying on implicit conversion based on your session NLS settings, which is never a good idea. You should use an explicit conversion of your string value with `to_timestamp()` and a suitable format mask.

The two things that look particularly suspicious are the two-digit year - if your `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` has YYYY that will be looking for 0018 rather than 2018; and possibly the hour value of 07 - you don't have an AM/PM marker so if your `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` has `HH:MI:SS,FF9 AM'` (or `HH:... PM`, or `HH:...` without either AM or PM) then you could be looking at the wrong time of day.

If you have a fixed value you can use a timestamp literal:

```
delete from access
where timeStamp_column = timestamp '2018-04-13 07:15:31.123457000';
```

otherwise convert explicitly:

```
delete from access
where timeStamp_column = to_timestamp('13/04/18 07:15:31,123457000',
  'DD/MM/RR HH24:MI:SS,FF9');
```

(assuming it is really supposed to be 7AM of course; if it's supposed to be 7PM just change 07 to 19).